# Can I force my PHP C extension to link pthread at compile time?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

In my PHP extension, I have an m4 file `config.m4`. As I understand, when I run `phpize`, it generates a `configure` file from `config.m4`, and running `configure` generates the Makefile. In my `config.m4` file, I link in outside libraries with lines like

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(library,,EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_SUBST(EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

which results in the Makefile containing the line

```
EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD = -llibrary
```

However, when I try to link pthread by prepending the line

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(pthread,,EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

The relevant line in the Makefile does not change, even though it does if I replace `pthread` with `test_string`.

I also tried adding to `config.m4` the line `LIBS="-lpthread $LIBS"`, but that had no effect on the Makefile.

I finally tried adding the line `EXTRA_LDFLAGS=-lpthread` to `config.m4`, and even though it did start passing `-lpthread` to the compiler, the flag came too early in the command line to have an effect. It seems that it has to come after the other libraries to work.

Is there anything I can do in `config.m4` that will result in `make` passing the argument `-lpthread` to `gcc` after the rest of the libraries in `EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the line

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(pthread,,EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

with

```
EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD="-lpthread $EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD"
```

This bypassed the check in `configure` that strips `-lpthread` from `EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD`.